# Replacing part of a string (Excel VBA)

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have the following data in Sheet 1:

```
                 A
1   1C BAC Z6 : CHF QM : 1M TOIS
2   2C BAC Z6 : CHF QM : 1M TOIS
3   3C BAC H7 : CHF QM : 1M TOIS
4   30C BAC H7 : CHF AM : 1M TOIS
5   45C BAC M7 : CHF QM : 1M TOIS
6   5C BAC Z7 : CHF QM : 1M TOIS
```

I'm trying to replace the 2-letter code that follows "BAC", but can't seem to do so using the REPLACE() function.  I'm not familiar enough with VBA to use InStr either.

**Background**:  the 2-character code that follows "BAC" represents a month and a year.

The first character in the 2-character code represents a month.  For example,

"H" represents March

"M" represents June

"U" represents September

"Z" represents December

There are only four months (March, June, September, December).

The second character in the 2-character code represents the year.  For example,

"6" represents 2016

"7" represents 2017

"8" represents 2018
etc, etc

Does anyone know of a solution that can replace the 2-character code with **next** 2-character code (i.e. the next month and year)?

For example,

"Z6" (December 2016) would become "H7" (March 2017)

"H7" (March 2017) would become "M7" (June 2017)

"M7" (June 2017) would become "U7" (September 2017)

"U7" (September 2017) would become "Z7" (December 2017)

"Z7" (December 2017) would become "H8" (March 2018)

etc, etc.

Thanks in advance for your help with this!

Comment: Just to clarify: A1 contains `1C BAC Z6 : CHF QM : 1M TOIS`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("BAC",A1)+4,2,VLOOKUP(MID(A1,FIND("BAC",A1)+4,1),{"H","M";"M","U";"U","Z";"Z","H"},2,FALSE)&MID(A1,FIND("BAC",A1)+5,1)+(MID(A1,FIND("BAC",A1)+4,1)="Z"))
```

We use the `REPLACE` function along with a `VLOOKUP` to determine what to replace the letter part of the code.

`FIND` locates the two character code to be replaced by `REPLACE` or examined with the `MID` function.

`VLOOKUP` decides  to replace H with M, M with U, etc

The Boolean equality test at the end decides to increment the number by one if and only if the letter is `Z`.

**EDIT:**  The OP indicated he might want to search for one of several codes preceding the part to be replaced.  This can be done by using an array constant in the `FIND` function *find_text* parameter.  We also add these constants on to the end of the string in order to avoid errors depending on which is not found.  `MIN` returns the smallest number which, if the key is found, will be within the key.

In this modification, I also used the `MOD` function so that **9** would roll over to **0**.

```
=REPLACE(A1,MIN(FIND({"BAC","EMC"},A1&"BACEMC"))+4,2,VLOOKUP(MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"BAC","EMC"},A1&"BACEMC"))+4,1),{"H","M";"M","U";"U","Z";"Z","H"},2,FALSE)&MOD(MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"BAC","EMC"},A1&"BACEMC"))+5,1)+(MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"BAC","EMC"},A1&"BACEMC"))+4,1)="Z"),10))
```

Comment: Nice use of `VLOOKUP()` with an internal array !

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks.  I tend to use that if the table is small, and unlikely to require maintenance in the future.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld - is it possible to update the formula such that it will work if the value in column A is "1Y CAM 1.75 EMC Z6 : CHF SB : 1M TOIS"?  (the major difference being that one has "CAM" and other has "BAC"?)

Comment: @equanimity Sure.  So long as you know how many spaces there are between `CAM` and your two character code.  If that value will vary, then I would use VBA and Regular Expressions, as a formula would be exceedingly complex.

Comment: @equanimity If you can key off `EMC`, then you just need to replace `BAC` with `EMC`.  If you must key off `CAM`, then make that change and also change the addition to the `MID` *start_number* parameter.

Comment: Yes, we can definitely key off of "EMC".  The problem I'm having is that we don't know whether the value will be something like "1C BAC Z6 : CHF QM : 1M TOIS" or "1Y CAM 1.75 EMC Z6 : CHF SB : 1M TOIS".  So, is it possible to have something like `OR(FIND("CME",D3)+4, FIND("CME",D3)+4)` as the second argument for the start_num argument in `REPLACE()`?

Comment: @equanimity One way is to use an array constant in the `FIND` function.  So long as you don't have the **key** included in any string before its occurrence, you could replace the `FIND` with `MIN(FIND({"BAC","EMC"},A1&"BACEMC"))`